# Почему не работает LINQ запрос?

Tags: c#, linq

Делаю linq запрос такого вида

```
var request = from a in db.Contacts
                  join c in db.Companies on a.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID into ljoin1
                  from Company in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()


                  select new
                  {
                      a.Surname,
                      a.Name,
                      a.Middlename,
                      c.CompanyName
                  };
```

Не видит переменную `c` . Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная `с` "спряталась" потому что вы использовали операцию `GroupJoin` (`join ... into ljoin1`).

Строчкой ниже вы обозвали нужный вам объект `Company`. Наверное, вам надо исправить его на `c`:

```
              join c in db.Companies on a.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID into ljoin1
              from c in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```